# validatin script for radio button not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arraylist

I am getting errors. The script is not working. Help
thanks in advance.
I want to check if all my set of radio buttons are checked when button next is click.
other ways of doing this also are welcome

```
 <div class="qheader">
 9) What's the world's most widely spoken language?</div>
 <div class="qselections">
 <input type="radio" value="a" name="question9">a) English<br>
 <input type="radio" value="b" name="question9">b) Spanish<br>
 <input type="radio" value="c" name="question9">c) Mandarin<br>
 <input type="radio" value="d" name="question9">d) French<br>
 </div><br>

 <div class="qheader">
 10) Which continent is host to the most countries in the world?</div>
 <div class="qselections">
 <input type="radio" value="a" name="question10">a) Asia<br>
 <input type="radio" value="b" name="question10">b) Africa<br>
 <input type="radio" value="c" name="question10">c) Europe<br>
 </div>
 </div>
 <input type="button" value="Next" name="B3" onclick="showdesc()">

 <script>
        $(function() {
            $(document).on('click', 'form', function () {

                var validate = true;
               var unanswered = new Array();

               // Loop through available sets
               $('.qselections').each(function () {
                // Question text
                var question = $(this).prev().text();
                // Validate
                if (!$(this).find('input').is(':checked')) {
                    // Didn't validate ... dispaly alert or do something
                    unanswered.push(question);

                    validate = false;
                }
            });

            if (unanswered.length > 0) {
                msg = "Please answer the following questions:\n" +         unanswered.join('\n'); 
                alert(msg);
            }
            return validate;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle for the same?

Comment: Where did you define showdesc()?

Comment: showdesc is in external and it works..
fiddle, sorry, i dont know how to do this..

Comment: problem is with the script.. it is giving error.. expected'{'

Comment: A fiddle is basically a working demo of your problem. Go to www.jsfiddle.net and try.

Comment: expected '{' on which line? I cannot seem to reproduce your error. It's working on my local machine. I'm trying in jsfiddle

Comment: I was able to get it working, but I'm not sure it is useful to you. I had to mess with your structure a bit. Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ed8qL/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function clicked() {

            var validate = true;
           var unanswered = new Array();

           // Loop through available sets
           $('.qselections').each(function () {
            // Question text
            var question = $(this).prev().text();
            // Validate
            if (!$(this).find('input').is(':checked')) {
                // Didn't validate ... dispaly alert or do something
                unanswered.push(question);

                validate = false;
            }
        });

        if (unanswered.length > 0) {
            msg = "Please answer the following questions:\n" +         unanswered.join('\n'); 
            alert(msg);
        }
        return validate;
    }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cebTe/)

I reproduced your problem with slight modifications, works well for me. I guess it's just a syntax error in the portion of your code, not present in the fiddle. Cross check and let me know.
Try and modify your click call, make it direct like in the fiddle.

Comment: That can be put in anytime :P

Comment: Sorry I had to edit and put the function inside the code block lol. It was driving me nuts!

Comment: No problem, glad that you did it :D

Comment: working perfectly in the fiddle, but not in my code :(
maybe problem is somewhere else.. :(

Comment: did you change your click code? you'd never click a form, you'd click a button. try changing the code to - $(document).on('click',/*button in the form*/, function ()

Answer (score 0):

```
    //try this script

    if(!$(this).find("input[name=radio]").is(':checked')){
        alert("hi");
    }
```

Comment: Ideally, his script is the same, if he had anything apart from radio buttons inside the div, your script makes much more sense. But there shouldn't be any change in functionality.